# Efficient Multithreaded File Processessing in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

This method in my code uses a producer-consumer design to read many files and process them for use in an NLP algorithm. The completion service collects files as they are processed, which means that `docId != index`. Given that I need to retrieve probabilities elsewhere where `docID == index`, I've implemented a priority queue to sort. However, I do this by sequentially retrieving documents from a list of futures and then putting them into the queue.

I know this implementation isn't great. I keep staring at the `concurrentskiplistset` thinking I should be able to implement it for better performance and not have these issues. I'm brand new to concurrency and Java, so I'm sure there's a lot to critique.

How can I make this multithreading more efficient?

**Vectorizer:**

```
public class Vectorizer {
public Vectorizer(){
}
public PriorityQueue<Document> readAll(File fileDir) 
throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, IOException{
    //read each file. When each file is vectorized, put it in a minibatch.
    //producer-consumer threading structure.
    int NUM_THREADS = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    BlockingQueue<LinkedList<String>> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(50);
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUM_THREADS);
    CompletionService<Document> completionService = 
               new ExecutorCompletionService<Document>(service);
    //TODO: is list the most efficient structure to handle future?
    List<Future<Document>> docs = new ArrayList<Future<Document>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < (NUM_THREADS - 1); i++) {
        docs.add(completionService.submit(new DocumentConsumer(queue)));
    }
    // Wait for ReadFile to complete
    service.submit(new ReadFile(queue, fileDir)).get();
    service.shutdownNow();  // interrupt CPUTasks
    // Wait for DocumentConsumer to complete
    service.awaitTermination(365, TimeUnit.DAYS);

    //do things with processed docs.
    //should I be doing this, though?
    PriorityQueue<Document> Documents = new PriorityQueue<Document>();
    for(Future<Document> d : docs){
        try{
        Document doc = d.get();
        Documents.add(doc);
        System.out.println(Integer.toString(doc.Cj));
        } catch(ExecutionException e) {
            e.getCause();e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return Documents;
}
```

**Document object (without compare and overload):**

```
public class Document implements Comparator<Document>{
int docId, Cj;
HashMap<String,Integer> termTable;
public Document(int id,int Cj, HashMap<String,Integer> termMap){
    this.docId = id;
    this.Cj = Cj;

    this.termTable = termMap;
}
```

`docId` is set during file reading. I read in a file and append the count to the first line, which is then set during processing.

The rest of the code is available [here](https://github.com/mtbarta/LDA_SCVB).

Answer (score 2):

I didn't look at the specific performance issue you described. However, my general review:

### Readability

```
for (int i = 0; i < (NUM_THREADS - 1); i++) {
    docs.add(completionService.submit(new DocumentConsumer(queue)));
}
```

Starting at 0 and ending at `somevalue - 1`. Why don't you start at 1? You don't even do anything with the index, so it's not like it matters.

```
        e.getCause();e.printStackTrace();
```

Don't put multiple statements on the same line. It turns your code into a wall of code. You think understanding a wall of text is hard? Try a wall of code...

### Naming

Use `camelCase` for methods and variables. Use `PascalCase` for types. Use `ALL_CAPS` for constants. This means that...

```
int NUM_THREADS = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
```

should be final and

```
PriorityQueue<Document> Documents = new PriorityQueue<Document>();
```

should be renamed to `documents`.

```
public Document(int id,int Cj, HashMap<String,Integer> termMap){
```

Should rename `Cj` to `cj`. ... And even better would be to rename it to something that explains what it is. Right now I have no idea what a `cj` is.